# FFMPEG .bat script not running

Tags: video, ffmpeg, scripting

I've got a folder full of .avi video files. I want to change the container of each of those to .mp4 using a .bat script.
This is the code:

```
for i in "*.avi" do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy "outputs/${i%.avi}.mp4"; done
```

But when i run the .bat cmd pops up for a split second and closes immediately. The folder for the output is there as well as the ffmpeg.exe.
Whats wrong?

Comment: hmmm, `.bat` and `ffmpeg.exe` file, are you running that script on windows on linux ? As the scripts looks like one of linux and not windows.

Comment: Im running it on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is mixed up having some of linux syntax, using `%%` over `${}` should do the trick.

```
for %%i in (*.avi) do echo %%i do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c copy "outputs/%%i.avi.mp4"
REM :this will hold screen until you press a key
pause
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!